# XSL-FO: Arabic characters are displayed as '########'

Tags: xslt, xsl-fo, apache-fop

I'm having trouble getting the Arabic characters on the PDF generated using fop 2.3 jar on JDK 1.8.

The PDF gets generated and the indentation of the text seems to be change but all Arabic characters appear as '########'.

Any pointers on what might be wrong here?

This is the snippet from xslt,

```
<fo:table-cell display-align="after">
    <fo:block padding-before="1em" padding-top="1pt" font-family="Amiri,Helvetica,FreeSans,FreeSerif,NotoSansCJK,ZawgyiOne,saysettha_ot,Hanuman" start-indent="0em" font-weight="bold" font-size="20.7pt" text-align="center" wrap-option="nowrap">
        <xsl:value-of select="$title"/>
    </fo:block>
</fo:table-cell>
```

Below is the content of the fop.xconf file,

```
<!-- arabic https://fonts.google.com/specimen/Amiri-->
<font embed-url="Amiri-Regular.ttf" kerning="yes">
        <font-triplet name="Amiri" style="italic" weight="bold"/>
        <font-triplet name="Amiri" style="normal" weight="bold"/>
        <font-triplet name="Amiri" style="italic" weight="normal"/>
        <font-triplet name="Amiri" style="normal" weight="normal"/>
</font>
```

Below font files are used,

```
Amiri-Bold.ttf
Amiri-BoldItalic.ttf
Amiri-Italic.ttf
Amiri-Regular.ttf
```

Comment: With a relative URL like `Amiri-Regular.ttf` in `font embed-url="Amiri-Regular.ttf"`, have you set `font-base` too? Are you running FOP from the command line? Does it show any warnings about fonts being not found?

Comment: Hello, i have not set the font-base explicitly in fop.xconf file , but in my java client I have the logic to refer to location where font files are placed.
final FopConfParser fopConfParser = new FopConfParser(fopConfFile, PACKAGE_RESOURCE_DIR.toURI());
#PACKAGE_RESOURCE_DIR - Location where the font files are placed.

In addition, i also tried to set below property and execute, but there are no exceptions thrown. 

  <strict-configuration>true</strict-configuration>
  
Even if i remove the font file and execute , still there are no exceptions thrown.

Comment: SOLVED - After adding the font-base configuration, it seems to work now. Thanks for your pointers.

Comment: Can you please specify the solution, What you did in the font configuration and where? I am facing the same issue 

I am new to Apache-FOP.

I use this to generate PDF documet from a XML input. I have created XSL for my input XML and getting ### values instead of Arabic text. Can any one please point out the mistake? I have set of fonts but still I cannot get the right result